# Is it possible to display kindle books with other software applications?

Tags: kindle

I would like to view and take notes on kindle books without the need of a kindle reader/software.  Is it possible to build a reader (and add notes) that can open the .kf8 format?

Comment: This may be of some use: http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/KF8

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can be built. But there are available open source options.

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) can open almost any ebook format for reading (and some of them - KF8, epub - for editing too).